# uncaught typeerror object object object has no method 'kendoUi' Error in Parsing

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

This is My JSonSctipt file code:

```
var data = [
    {
        "SearchResult": {
            "assets": [
                {
                    "agent": "6.1.0",
                    "id": 1,
                    "model": "Gateway1",
                    "modelId": 2,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "serialNumber": "Serial01"
                },
                {
                    "agent": "M2M",
                    "id": 2,
                    "model": "Gateway1",
                    "modelId": 3,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "serialNumber": "Serial02"
                }
            ],
            "searchCriteria": {
                "paginationEnabled": false,
                "rowsPerPage": -1,
                "startRow": -1,
                "totalAvailableRows": -1,
                "alternateId": {
                    "@xsi.nil": "true"
                },
                "modelNumber": {
                    "@xsi.nil": "true"
                },
                "name": "*",
                "serialNumber": {
                    "@xsi.nil": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: { 
    data: data,
    schema: {
      data: function(rawData) { 
        return rawData[0].SearchResult.assets;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Thsi is My Index.html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script src="scripts/hello-world.js"></script>
         <script src="kendo/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>


        <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>

 <div id="grid"></div>







    </body>
</html>
```

when i run this code uncaught typeerror object object object has no method 'kendoUi' Error I m getting so am Unable to Display data In Grid please tell me how i will fix it or can any one Please tell me  how i will Json parsing In Kendo UI

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Kendo Grid, which is a part of Kendo Web, but only have a reference to Kendo Mobile (i.e. kendo.mobile.min.js).  You need to add a script reference to either kendo.web.min.js or kendo.all.min.js.  Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xacto/Yzugr/), paying particular attention to the External Resource (i.e. kendo.all.min.js)

P.S.  SO won't let me post a link to jsfiddle without some code, so here is part of the code again, to satisfy their requirements:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
</head>
<bo 
         <div id="grid"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: What we have to Change actully This example am doing first time so am not able to Understnd how i will Do Josn Parsing of data and print it in Listview  or Grid yes this is part Kedno UI please help me